# how to reference a typedef within a class with an instance of such class?

Tags: c++, static, typedef

Is there a way to get this code work, just like it does when calling a *static* function with the dot notation?

```
struct A{
    static void f(){ }
    typedef int t;
};

template<typename T> void f(){}

int main(){
    A a;
    a.f();          //legit
    f<a.t>();       //‘a’ cannot appear in a constant-expression, ‘.’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
    a.t somevar;    //invalid use of ‘A::t’
    f<a::t>();      //‘a’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
    a::t somevar;   //‘a’ is not a class, namespace, or enumeration
}
```

EDIT:
Guys, please read the question and test your code before posting. The point here is NOT to use `A::t` but "invoke" `t` through an *instance* of `A`, like you can do with static methods.

Comment: How in the world do you *"invoke"* a typedef???

Comment: `t` is a **type**, not a variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `A::t` instead of `a.t` because the typedef is like `static` and `a` is an instance of `A`.

---

**EDIT**: In contrast to what I said above, it is not always "like `static`".  For static members, there is this special rule:

> A static member s of class X may be referred to using the qualified-id expression X::s; it is not necessary to
>   use the class member access syntax (5.2.5) to refer to a static member. A static member may be referred
>   to using the class member access syntax, in which case the object expression is evaluated. 
>      [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct process {
>   static void reschedule();
> };
> process& g();
>
> void f() {
>   process::reschedule(); // OK: no object necessary
>   g().reschedule();      // g() is called
> }
> ```

Since a `typedef` is *not* a static member, this syntax is invalid.

Given the instance `a` and not this syntactic sugar, the only way to get `t` is to get the type of it.  C++11 gives us a tool for that:

```
typedef decltype(a) a_type;
f<a_type::t>();
a_type::t somevar;
```

However, I see no practical use of it (ok, maybe in macros, but everyone knows that templates are better).

Comment: What do you mean the typedef is static?

Comment: You can not have a static typedef in a class.

Comment: @user1333488 a typedef behaving like a static... can you explain please?

Comment: It is a property of the class and works without an instance, just like static functions and static variables (of a class). Furthermore, the syntax is just like accessing a static variable.

Comment: the question was actually if there was a "sintax sugar" like for static methods (you can call a static method with the dot notation from an instance of a certain class).

Comment: @user1333488 his typedef is not static.

Comment: there is no such thing as a "static typedef" afaik. A typedef within a class is inherently "static" because it does not make sense to think it as a property of an instance of the class.

Comment: A typedef can not be static as they are both storage containers, and you can't have two storage containers on the same variable.

Comment: It's funny how he never said "static typedef" but everyone insist on saying "hey, static typedefs do not exist".

Comment: Ok, the last edit is finally what I'm looking for. *Whew*. Anyway, it's basically a "no": there's no syntax sugar like the one that let you call static member functions as they were non static.

Comment: @user1333488: I don't really appreciate it that you copy the correct on-topic answer from another reply...

Comment: I didn't saw your answer while editing (don't know why stackoverflow hides all other answers on editing). I'm really sorry for that, @BertR.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use scope resolution operator (and return int value from `main`):

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    A::t somevar = 0;
    return 0;    
}
```

Note that type alias introduced with `typedef` must be publicly visible if you want to use it outside the class. If you had:

```
class A
{
    static void f(){}
    typedef int t;
};
```

Then using A::t like in the above example would yield compiler error (*"cannot access private typedef..."*). You would need to use `public` accessor specifier:

```
class A
{
    static void f(){}
public:
    typedef int t;
};
```

Comment: The first part was already said by 2 previous answers some time ago, the second part is wrong. You should return int from main, but you don't need to.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
typedef decltype (a) AT;
typedef AT::t T;
f<T>();
T somevar;
```

decltype is specific for C++11

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the scope resolution operator, so the could would need to be

```
f<A::t>();
A::t somevar;
```

For more information on the scope resolution operator, take a look at [C++ Scope Resolution Operator ::](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp7a.doc/language/ref/clrc05cplr175.htm).